# Computing Excess Green Vegetation Index (ExG) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, digital-image-processing, image-classification, vegetation-index

I have to process the image for Sugarcane row detection and extraction.

Sample image is accessible from the link: https://github.com/AndresHerrera/croprows_generator_pa_v2/tree/master/droneimages

I have to calculate Excess Green Vegetation Index (ExG) in QGIS to highlight green regions.

How to I compute ExG index using QGIS to have a result as in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. Question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383807/image-enhancement-in-qgis was w.r.t. Image Enhancement. I added a comment: "image enhancement is applied to facilitate visual interpretation and understanding of images. The enhancement will not change the radiometric values ​​of the objects in the image". I need assistance to compute ExG index using QGIS

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest OTB **BandMath** tool (from `QGIS Processing Toolbox > OTB > Image Manipulation`), which can handle bands calculation.

Given `ExG = 2 * G - R - B`, the corresponding OTB Expression is `2*im1b2 - im1b1 - im1b3`.

(Please note `im1` means the first image and each band is represented as `b1` = red, `b2`= green and `b3` = blue).

[image]

(Above: `Output Image` - used as input for this process - is the contrast enhanced image from your `Raster_orthomosaic` layer).

(Below: ExG output)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will apply your recommendations and leave you a feedback.

Comment: I mistakenly posted the results as an answer. Output raster was generated but with an Error: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: cannot find proj.db.Can you kindly provide details of Tool and parameters used for contrast enhanced image.

Comment: @HansrajR I think you have posted another [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383807/image-enhancement-in-qgis) dedicated to the Image Enhancement. Please refine that question to focus on the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you have some issue with OTB, it can also be used **Raster Calculator** as follows:

[image]

After click in OK, result is totally equivalent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insight. Can you kindly provide details of Tool and parameters used for contrast enhanced image.

Comment: I used default values as it expressed in my images. No additional details are needed.